# How to parse/decode JSON object in smarty template?

Tags: php, smarty, json, smarty3

I have the following code in my template file:

```
{foreach from=$items item=entry}
  <pre>
    {$entry->nb_persons|@print_r}
  </pre>
{/foreach}
```

The output is (json string):

> `{"ip":"12.12.12.12","date":1375616434,"cartitems":["foo:1"],"company":"dsad","FirstName":"sad","LastName":"asdsad","street":"","postcode":"","city":"","country":"Andorra","phone":"456456","fax":"","email":"sad@sad.com","comefrom":"google","request":"","message":"sadads"}`

I would like to print each element seperated, for example :

> `{$entry->nb_persons.company}`

Should give me -> "dsad"

But this is not working and I'm not sure why.

Comment: What do you mean by separated?

Comment: Thanks Jhon' I meant print only the value as shoven above {$entry->nb_persons.company} -> "dsad". Thanks again...

Answer (score 16, accepted):

JSON string is just string. To access its members you have to create array/object from this string:

```
{foreach from=$items item=entry}
  {* create array from JSON string*}
  {assign var=person value=$entry->nb_persons|json_decode:1}
  <pre>
    {$person.company}
  </pre>
{/foreach}
```

Comment: @cookie669 May I ask why have you changed accepted answer? If something is wrong with my version, let me know.

Answer (score 3):

I'm not an expert with Smarty, but I think you're trying to access the property of a JSON structured string.
Try to decode it first to an object and then access it.

Something like this:

```
{foreach $items as $entry}
  {assign var="person" value="{$entry->nb_persons|@json_decode}"}
  <pre>
    {$person.company}
  </pre>
{/foreach}
```

I didn't test it, though.

Good luck!